# Getting a Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control error

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm getting a "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control." error message. I've looked here to see what others have said about that error. It looks to me as though some people have gotten the binding syntax wrong. I believe I am using the correct data binding, but I could be wrong. The error occurs on the first line of the DropDownList. I'm using VS 2015.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUsersRating" AutoPostBack="True"
    DataSourceID="sdsUserRatings" DataTextField="RatingID"
    DataValueField="RatingID" Height="16px"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RatingID") %>'
    AppendDataBoundItems="False"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsersRating_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">(Select a Rating)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsUserRatings" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VideoLibraryConnectionString %>"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO UserRatings(UserID, ShowID, RatingID) VALUES (@UserID, @ShowID, @RatingID)"
    SelectCommand="SELECT UserRatings.RatingID FROM UserRatings INNER JOIN Users ON UserRatings.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE (UserRatings.ShowID = @ShowID) AND (Users.UserID = @UserID)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE UserRatings SET RatingID = @RatingID WHERE (UserID = @UserID) AND (ShowID = @ShowID)" OnInserted="sdsUserRatings_Inserted">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlUsers" Name="UserID"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:RouteParameter Name="ShowID" RouteKey="ShowID" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlUsersRating" Name="RatingID"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:RouteParameter Name="ShowID" RouteKey="ShowID" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlUsers" Name="UserID"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlUsersRating" Name="RatingID"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlUsers" Name="UserID"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:RouteParameter Name="ShowID" RouteKey="ShowID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you can only use `Bind`, `Eval`, `XPath` if your object is `DataBound` meaning it has `DataSource`.

As per seeing your `DropDownList` you have embedded static values in it Blank, 1 - 5.

Remove this property from your `DropDownList` : `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RatingID") %>'`

Then to do this..

On one of your form events, let's say `Load`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load()
    Dim RatingID = (some select query here to get RatingID)

    ddlUserRating.ClearSelection()
    ddlUserRating.Items.FindByValue(RatingID).Selected = True
End Sub
```